# Perl significance of $#_ variable

Tags: perl

I see when I loop through elements of an array, and test $#_ , I get -1 for each element.  I am hoping someone can explain what this variable does, and what it is used for most often.

Comment: Do you mean `$_` or `$#`? Because `perldoc -v "$#_"` isn't returning anything...

Comment: I don't need to show my code if you understand what the variable does/holds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like `$#foo` is the last existing index of array `@foo`, `$#_` is the last existing index of array `@_`. If `@_` is empty, `$#_` is `-1`.

It sounds like you mean to use `$_`. `$_` is aliased by foreach, `map` and `grep` loops to the element current being processed. `while (<>)` also sets `$_` (as it gets rewritten to `while (defined($_ = <>))`). As a result, `$_` is used as the default argument by many builtins (e.g. `say`).

```
 # Print each element on its own line
 say for @a;
```

is short for

```
 # Print each element on its own line
 say $_ for @a;
```

which is the terse form of

```
 # Print each element on its own line
 for my $ele (@a) {
    say $ele;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean `$_` which is a special variable in Perl.  It holds the current value while looping through a list element.  For instance, below will print out each element of @foo, one at a time.

```
foreach (@foo) {
  print $_;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't.  Please see the other answer.